# Syntax for custom method on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, oop

I am creating a Python module that does a variety of things. One function I am trying to make is one that calculates trailing returns given a column in a dataframe. From a user point of view, the way I would like to invoke the method would be like this:

```
import my_module

df2 = df1.trailing_returns(column='1 Mth Returns')
```

However, I cannot figure out how to write my class in such a way. The only way I know how to perform an operation like this would be to do:

```
import my_module

df2 = my_module.trailing_returns(df1, column='1 Mth Returns')
```

The research that I have done so far has basically told me that libraries like Pandas are able to invoke method like this (i.e. using dataframe.merge vs pd.merge(dataframe)) because the type pd.DataFrame is defined within the library, and that there's really no way to replicate this without modifying the pandas library. In summary, is it possible to invoke a custom method directly on a dataframe, or must it be called in some other manner?

Comment: I believe the search term you are looking for is "monkey patch". Check out [this answer/example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466499/2221001) that monkey patches a method into pandas.